# OpenLayers. External ArcGISCache layer has different zoom levels/scales than current map in use

Tags: openlayers-2

Current map has 40 zoom levels. Map uses mostly internal layers but for this one special layer an external service is used and that is where ArcGISCache comes in. This ArcGISCache layer has its layer info fetched with `OpenLayers.Protocol.Script.createRequest()`. When an attemp to draw the layer is made a method called `ArcGISCache.getURL` asks map for current zoom level and it reports 23. However `ArcGISCache.lods` property has only 13 elements and error is thrown `Cannot read property 'startTileCol' of undefined` (used caps in the code to mark the place)

```
getURL: function(a) {
   ...
   a = this.map.getZoom();
       if (this.lods) {
           if (b = this.lods[this.map.getZoom()], c < B.STARTTILECOL || c > 
               b.endTileCol || d < b.startTileRow || d > b.endTileRow)
                return null
        } else {
           ...
        }
...
}
```

How do I integrate this new external ArcGISCache layer into the exising map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have mapped resolutions and scales of my base map to resolutions and scales of ArcGISCache layer then overriden getURL function to pick correct lod by `this.lods[this.map.getZoom()]` and check if lod exists. Having problems with tile placing on the grid because of different resolutions though